Change cipher PBEWithMD5AndDES
I am using PostgreSQL 14. I created a database, set up a user, and performed a migration.
Now, the database is connected to the application, and a security test was conducted.
I have been tasked with changing the encryption algorithm PBEWithMD5AndDES used for storing passwords in the PARAMETER database table because it is weak.
I am not exactly sure how to do this. Can someone advise me?

It's a Java thing! Not sure how you can do this in PostgreSQL! Do you know the values of the parameters - i.e. the plain text?

Does it have to be changed in Java? Is there a procedure? From what I have found, PBEWithMD5AndDES is the default.

It's not a PostgreSQL default! The encryption is done by the app and the ciphertext is stored in the database! If you want to change this, then you'll have to modify the app - the db in this case is just a bitbucket storing the ciphertext!
